# SQL Help ~ Relational Database Model ~ Displaying Results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Currently I have a database with about 10 tables.  I have successfully joined them all together using inner joins and have displayed the results.

However, I am having trouble where one column could have multiple values attributed to it.

For example, my database has this loaded into it:

```
item    id
item1 | 1
item2 | 1
item2 | 2
item2 | 3
```

I joined it like this:

```
SELECT Main.item, thing.id FROM Main INNER JOIN thing ON Main.MainID = thing.id
```

I would like to concatenate the three instances of 'id' together for item2, without displaying 'item2' three times on my results page.  A delimiter between 'id's might be '&', where the result would be:

```
"item1" "1"
"item2" "1 & 2 & 3"
```

I am pretty sure my problem is in my inadequate use of SQL but I am also using Javascript, PHP, & HTML to display the results so please let me know if you think that might be where the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: can you please add some code of yours so that it would be a little clear

Comment: I've seen some solutions in MS SQL (non standard, which is how I think you'd find most solutions), so I think it might help to mention the database type (MS SQL MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc).  Otherwise, consider just processing the rows in PHP before you output to the grid (I'm assuming it is a grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by your item and use `GROUP_CONCAT` as aggregate on your ids:

```
SELECT items.item, GROUP_CONCAT(ids.id SEPARATOR ' & ')
FROM items
JOIN ids ON items.id=ids.id
GROUP BY items.item
```

See [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function for more information.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea this function existed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you can create groups (GROUP BY) and then you can use the GROUP_CONCAT MySQL function.

[MSSQL "GROUP_CONCAT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)